# java garbage collection - pausing for application threads?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

Total time for which application threads were stopped: xxxxxxxxx
Application Time: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

What do these two fields mean? Are my applications pausing for a gc? what does the application time field mean?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, based on the GC algorithm you are using your application thread may be stopped while GC.

As per [Tuning Garbage Collection with the 5.0, section 5.4](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/gc-tuning-5-138395.html):

> For each major collection the concurrent collector will pause all the application threads for a brief period at the beginning of the collection and toward the middle of the collection

**Application Time:** The time spent outside of garbage collection (referred to as application time)

Comment: i see, thank you. so application thread was stopped for a certain amount of time - then what does application time field itself mean?

Comment: Where did you find this "Application Time"? Are you using any tool?

Comment: im just reading a java gc log file and they contain these two fields being printed repeatedly with different values

Comment: Refer "Ergonomics" section of the link I have provided.  "the time spent outside of garbage collection (referred to as application time)"

Answer (score 0):

There are two types of GC, one of them are blocks the other threads.
You may found some details here: [GC types](http://javarevisited.blogspot.hu/2011/04/garbage-collection-in-java.html)